How to Build the Flutter Engine with Software Rendering as the Graphics Backend?
I am trying to build the Flutter engine from source with software rendering as the primary graphics backend. My goal is to disable GPU acceleration and force the engine to render everything using the CPU.
I’ve come across a few references to Skia’s software backend and some engine flags that might achieve this, but I’m unsure about the exact steps to configure and build the engine with these changes.
Could anyone guide me through the process or provide any specific build configuration settings to achieve this?
Here are a few questions I have:

Which flags or build configurations should I modify in the engine
source to enable software rendering?

Is it necessary to tweak anything specific in Skia for this setup?

How can I test or verify that software rendering is being used after
building the engine?

Are there any performance caveats or issues I should expect with
software rendering in Flutter?


I’ve already set up the Flutter engine build environment and successfully built the engine with default settings. Any detailed guidance on enabling software rendering would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance!
